# If I'm counting the number of binary strings of a certain length with a certain number of 1's, should I use combinations or permutations?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

And should I use repetition allowed, or repetition not allowed formula?

A binary string is a string with 1's and 0's in a row. {0,1} is a different string from {1,0}. Say I'm considering binary strings of length 6 and I want to count the number of strings with 3 1s (and 3 0s). Should this be regarded as a combination or permutation problem? And is this considered to be "repetition allowed?" It seems like it's "repetition required."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can often solve a counting problem by working out in how many ways you can choose the required object.  When doing so, there are a number of questions that are nearly always worth asking yourself.

1. *What am I choosing?*  In this example, are you choosing the $1$ or the $0$s?  No - you know all about these, there are three $1$s and three $0$s.  What you are choosing is the *places* in which the $1$s and $0$s will occur.  In this case, once you have chosen the places for the $1$s you know where the $0$s go (namely, in all the remaining places), so we only have to choose places for the $1$s.
2. So, you have to choose three places from six possibilities.  *Is repetition allowed?*  If you are not sure, make up a specific instance and ask whether or not it makes sense.  So, could we put three $1$s in places $6,6$ and $6$?  Obviously not - the three $1$s must go in different places.  **Note** how important question 1 is - if you thought you were choosing the $1$s (rather than the places) you would certainly say that repetition is allowed because there are three of them.  This would be wrong.
3. *Is order important?*  Once again, if you are not sure, ask yourself about a specific instance.  For example, if I choose to put $1$s in places $1,2$ and $4$, is that the same or different from putting them in places $2,4$ and $1$?  I hope it is clear that it is the same (the word is $110100$ in both cases) and therefore order is not important.

So, we have to choose $3$ places from $6$, with repetition not allowed and order not important, and the number of ways to do this is $C(6,3)$.

Comment: What is the C function ?

Comment: So apparently choosing n over k can be written as C function in english, have never seen that before.

Comment: There are at least three notations for this quantity:$$\binom nk\quad\hbox{and}\quad C(n,k)\quad\hbox{and}\quad {}^nC_k$$all mean the same thing.